# Jquery slider won't slide properly :/

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get this script to go both ways. I've managed to get this first script to move the current panel to the right, and then slide the new one in from left to right:

```
jQuery(function($) {

    $('a.slider_panel').click(function() {
        var $target = $($(this).attr('href')),
            $other = $target.siblings('.active');

        if (!$target.hasClass('active')) {
            $other.each(function(index, self) {
                var $this = $(this);
                $this.removeClass('active').animate({
                    left: $this.width()
                },500);
            });

            $target.addClass('active').show().css({
                left: -($target.width())
            }).animate({
                left: 0
            },500);
        }
    });
    $('div.slider_panel').first().addClass('active');
    $('div.slider_panel.active').show();
});
```

My problem is with this one, which is me trying to reverse this so I can move the current panel to the left, and then the new panel from right to left.

```
jQuery(function($) {

    $('a.slider_panel_back').click(function() {
        var $target = $($(this).attr('href')),
            $other = $target.siblings('.active');

        if (!$target.hasClass('active')) {
            $other.each(function(index, self) {
                var $this = $(this);
                $this.removeClass('active').animate({
                    right: $this.width()
                },500);
            });

            $target.addClass('active').show().css({
                right: -($target.width())
            }).animate({
                right: 0
            },500);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you create a http://jsfiddle.net/ to recreate the problem

Comment: @ArunPJohny - It's on jsbin, pretty much the same thing: http://jsbin.com/amuvuc/1/

Comment: @ArunPJohny - Managed to get it to work... Kinda... Click back and forth here and after 2 or 3 times you'll see it bug out. How can I fix this? http://jsbin.com/amuvuc/2/

Comment: Can you try http://jsbin.com/amuvuc/7#computers